# What is the biblical basis for baptism by sprinkling?

Tags: biblical-basis, baptism

As noted in the other question, there are two modes of water baptism of which I am familiar--immersion and sprinkling. As far as I know Catholics practice sprinkling along with many Protestant traditions, although many other Protestant traditions practice immersion.

What is the biblical basis for baptism by sprinkling according to those who have a literal interpretation of the Bible?

Comment: Worth noting: [Can.  854 Baptism is to be conferred either by immersion or by pouring; the prescripts of the conference of bishops are to be observed.](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2V.HTM)  but the question is still valid.

Comment: The question of infant baptism has already been asked here:  [What traditions espouse infant baptism and why?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1678).

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly (although I'm sure Narnian knows this) that the technical term *sprinkling* in respect of baptism doesn't mean a gentle act like sprinkling salt, but does in fact mean pouring. It may be pouring from the hand, or with an implement like a shell, or even a jug; but it does not mean sprinkling drops from the fingers.

Comment: **Mod Notice:** I have removed a whole pile of answers from this question that were obviously way out of line with our site guidelines. This question may only be answered _from the perspective of people who think there is scriptural support for sprinkling_. **Saying it's an invalid practice is _Not An Answer_ per our rules on matching the scope of answers to the question**. Also debating infant/adult baptism is not the subject of the question even though it is tangentially related, this is about sprinkling as opposed to immersion, not paedo vs. believer baptism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catholics don't baptize by sprinkling water, we pour it over the baptized's head, if there's just a font.

If you read Acts 8:24, you probably think baptism by immersion if that how baptism happens in your tradition, but if baptism is usually performed by pouring, then this is what your minds eye produces:

[image: Philip baptizing a eunuch]

Philip baptizing a eunuch by [Abel de Pujol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_de_Pujol)

Canonically, either is permissible in the Catholic Church.

[Sprinkling is biblical](http://www.upc-orlando.com/resources/written/doctrines/doctrine01.html),  but it's usually connected with blood.  But, since we're "baptized into His death", then I think the water of baptism may represent Jesus blood in some way, especially since that was what poured forth from His side when He was pierced on the cross.

Comment: Acts 8:38 And he commanded the chariot to stand still: and they went down both into the water, both Philip and the eunuch; and he baptized him

Acts 8:39 And when they were come up out of the water, the Spirit of the Lord caught away Philip, that the eunuch saw him no more: and he went on his way rejoicing.

Comment: Acts 8:24 does not speak of Baptism. "Then Simon answered, “Pray to the Lord for me so that nothing you have said may happen to me.”

Comment: @user4562: I converted your answer into a comment on this answer. Please see the [About] page to see how our site works and note that you need [50 rep to comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) on posts other than your own.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a basis for sprinkling.

Ezekiel 36:25-27. " I will sprinkle clean water on you, and you will become clean; I will cleanse you from all your uncleanness and from all your disgusting idols. 26 I will give you a new heart and put a new spirit inside you. I will remove the heart of stone from your body and give you a heart of flesh. 27 I will put my spirit inside you, and I will cause you to walk in my regulations, and you will observe and carry out my judicial decisions."

Comment: P.S. The verb translated as "sprinkle," likely means "splash." NET Bible on Lev. 1:5 (where the verb also occurs): “Splash” (cf. NAB) or “dash” (cf. NRSV) is better than “sprinkle,” which is the common English translation of this verb (זָרַק, zaraq; see, e.g., KJV, NASB, NIV, NLT). “Sprinkle” is not strong enough (contrast נָזָה [nazah], which does indeed mean “to sprinkle” or “to splatter”; cf. Lev 4:6).

Answer (score -1):

Sprinkling or pouring is a standard Old Testament practice associated with cleansing and anointing. Immersion would have been foreign to the Jews, who were familiar with Old Testament practices.

Comment: If you could expand this answer to contrast that point about old Jewish practice with the people being baptized in the river(John the Baptist), it would improve it, as well as comparing that to some early Christian traditions of full immersion.